# Firebase crash reporting causing crashes on iOS 10

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I noticed that since iOS 10 release I have couple of crashes refers to firebase library system monitoring.

```
   Crashed: com.google.system-monitoring
   SIGABRT ABORT 0x0000000186c58ff0
   -[FCRSystemMetadata sampleMemoryStats] + 4300660144
```

I already updated to the latest version of firebase on my app, but is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Me too... I'm experiencing A LOT of these crashes: https://gist.github.com/holgersindbaek/8a3291c051c139f2fb1823ee1d5f98e0

Comment: My app is using ios 10 and works fine with firebase, don't think is related to ios version

Comment: @FrankerZ the problem appears in iOS 10 beta, since then I removed Firebase crash reporting. Maybe they already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, Firebase does not work on iOS 10, neither a device nor a simulator.  This is a work in progress, so please stay tuned for updates.  You can follow general discussion on Firebase at the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) group, and the [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/) will have announcements as they occur.